# Selecting text inside li element, not childs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this list:

```
<ul id="expList">
    <li class="boldFont">Skills and technologies
        <ul>
            <li class="boldFont">.NET
                <ul>
                    <li>C#</li>
                    <li>ASP.NET</li>
                    <li>ADO.NET Entity framework</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont">Data access
                <ul>
                    <li>SQL</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont">Web
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML5</li>
                    <li>CSS3</li>
                    <li>jQuery</li>
                    <li>javaScript</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont">Graphic design
                <ul>
                    <li>Photoshop</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select `li` elements that has `ul` inside (expandable `li`, I use jQuery to make the list expandable).
That means that I want to style the text inside li: **Skills and technologies**, **.NET**, **Data access**, **Web**, **Graphic design**, not the childs.
I've tried to add a class `boldFont` directly to my target, but this affected on all childs.

Comment: Always show the attempts towards solving the problem. Edit the question and add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using !important on your css:

```
li.boldFont {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
ul li.boldFont li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L99c28kf/

But I don't think it's the best solution.
You can add a `<span>` instead of the boldFont class and use css to make them bold (with some selector like `li > span`), or simply use a `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a selector:

```
$("#expList li:has(ul)").somefunction()
```

Comment: But this *is* already fully supported by JQuery - which was my example - just that JQuery cannot take advantage of underlying DOM functions for absolute performance  (see https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry. Have an upvote by way of apology.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the words you want bold in `span` tags and style those? Example:

```css
ul#expList li > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="expList">
    <li class="boldFont"><span>Skills and technologies</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="boldFont"><span>.NET</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>C#</li>
                    <li>ASP.NET</li>
                    <li>ADO.NET Entity framework</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont"><span>Data access</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>SQL</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont"><span>Web</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML5</li>
                    <li>CSS3</li>
                    <li>jQuery</li>
                    <li>javaScript</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="boldFont"><span>Graphic design</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Photoshop</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```